# How to Create views for the field created through Lookup Column

Tags: view

I am having difficulty when creating views for the  users(managers) who have to see their own list assigned to them.

I created a form and used  people picker for users(managers) to assign the task  to them. While creating the views , I want the users( managers) to see their respective list and I have accomplished that using the filter[Me].

However, if I use lookup column to search from the other list instead of Peoplepicker,  I have difficulty to create the filter in the views to see the list using [Me]

Request your suggestion  to create the above view  for the field created through Lookup Colum

Answer (score 0):

From your question looks like you want to have something of a connected webpart feature. 
It will be too long to write about how to get started with connected webparts but you can have a look at this document

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-Web-Parts-54a36fda-019c-49b3-ad33-0cd94bf70c1e